# paypal sandbox return link to website missing

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I think I'm losing my mind...  I've been testing in the Paypal sandbox for a couple months now.  as of the last week (starting around 3/23/13) very odd and different things have been happening (or not happening) in the sandbox.
1)  had been getting mysql_select_db(): 27 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in (website location) where that had never happened before (code did not change) in ipn.php, which is the IPN validation php page.

2)  link to return back to website is now missing.  used to be on last page of sandbox after payment verified.  now, it just displays the txn_id in the last page AND LEAVES YOU THERE!!

what the heck happened???

Comment: I'm sure both issues are related, i.e. the db error and the missing redirect url.

Comment: can you elaborate @Jack because I am completely lost. what doesn't make sense it that it was working fine just last week.  not only that, the line of code where the error takes place is in an include file that is literally used site wide. not having any issues on the site and (as I said) it was working before.  just very odd.

Comment: ** issue resolved **  posting this for anyone who happens by.  MY issue with the ipn.php page (as @Jack suggested) was with the mySql resource. while I do not specifically recall seeing this stated anywhere (which means nothing to anyone but me ;) ), once a mySql reference has been acquired/assigned in a PHP page, it does not like it if you free the resource (mysql_free_result()) and then go acquire/assign it again.  acquire once at the beginning, do everything you need to do, free it up once at the end.  documented the hell out of this one.     ;)

Comment: one side note... the link back to the seller website in PayPal sandbox is STILL missing.  can't answer to THAT one.